# not able to perform comparison between two TIMESTAMP columns in apache beam

Tags: apache-beam

I'm trying to compare between two columns which are declared as TIMESTAMP datatype like below :

```
select a.*, ROUND(SUM(b.CausalValue),2) as GRPs from table1 a 
left join table2 b
    on a.Channel   = b.Outlet and
    a.SubBrand = b.SubBrand and 
    a.Event = b.SalesComponent and
    b.Week >= a.PeriodStartDate and
    b.Week <= a.PeriodEndDate
    group by Vehicle,Campaign,Copy,Event,CatLib
```

Week, PeriodStartDate  and PeriodEndDate are declared as TIMESTAMP and I'm not able to perform this operation. 
What my understanding as of now is may be beamSql does not allow comparison between two TIMESTAMP columns.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Anton, @Andrew : Well I agree that this feature is not implemented yet and what I did is I replaced timestamp with Date datatype and then converted the date column into BigInt (using extract and concat functions of sql) and then did the comparison and it worked perfectly fine. 
Thanks alot guys .

Answer (score 1):

Correct, at the moment comparison of date, time, timestamp, interval types is not implemented yet

Comment: @nagesh, in the meantime, you can use some combination of the built-in date functions to achieve date/timestamp comparison. Not elegant, but this is a workaround for now. Reference: [Built-in SQL functions](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/#built-in-functions).